# Ridiculously slow queries on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance, sql

I'm getting really slow queries in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on my dev machine. This problem has been plaguing me for about a month. Other developers don't have the same problem, but we all run the same code. It seems to be that any query that includes a `JOIN` takes >20s, some taking up to a minute. Inserts and updates are fast. The total database size is about 30MB, so it's hardly huge.

During the laggy queries, the CPU usage stays flat, the IO rates stay low, and the pagefault delta stays low too. I've not tweaked any performance settings in the db config - it's all stock from the setup.

The software that connects to the SQL server is running on the same machine as it. I've tried multiple dev database copies, and customer databases that are known to be fine, all to no avail.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: A raw guess: have a look at the system log to see if any disk failure

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT No entries in there but the usual service control manager notifications. It's a brand new machine, too.

Comment: Any difference in anti-virus?  You could run Belarc your machine and someone else's, see what's different.

Comment: @gravyface All dev machines run MSSE, configured to skip scanning MDF and LDF files in the data directory.

Comment: I'd still do the Belarc.

Comment: Some of us run WinXP, some run Vista, some run Win7. Belarc isn't going to give me anything useful.

Comment: You're very quick to dismiss any suggestions, but yet you don't have the answer.  Could be a difference in hotfixes installed, for example.

Comment: @gravyface Sorry, I didn't mean to come across as dismissive. I'm just not confident that there'll be any way to identify differences between dev machine states when we're all running different operating systems. I suspect the issue is to do with MSSQL configuration - maybe it chose something unusual for one of its auto-configured values, I don't know. No idea how to check, either.

Comment: I am not sure how valid any testing will be.  If you are all running different OS setups then there are so many variables.  You have a machine running XP(10 yr old OS) and compare it to Win7(3-4 yr old)\

Comment: @mikewest235 Exactly my point. I'm not intending to compare machines, just to solve this performance issue. Are there any performance vars in the server that might cause such an issue?

Comment: this statement has me confused " MS SQL Server 2008 R2 on my dev machine"  is the sql a virtual on your dev workstation?

Comment: @tonyroth Everyone has the DBMS installed on their laptop. It's just for local testing, there's no shared db.

Comment: Are you testing by running queries directly in SSMS, or testing via the app that connects to the database?

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown Via the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have a lot of BLOBs (Binary Large OBJectS) stored in your database.  That happens if you store very large binary objects in your db, such as other databases, or perhaps zip packages or whatnot.

That can become a performance killer, and is quite possible if you allow folks to upload files through something like Sharepoint.

Comment: This might actually be something. We store attached files to some records as BLOB. They're only a few hundred KB each (mainly JPEGs / XLS files). I've got a couple of ideas about where this might be slow. This gives me a few avenues to look at, thanks :)

Comment: This was (part of) the problem. We were creating a background task that pulled out the files into memory for caching, which left a dataset open. For each row we pulled, we did another query to get some user info. I'm not sure why, but when I moved everything around into a JOIN and removed the extra queries, everything runs smoothly. Interestingly, when I checked query execution time, it only took a few milliseconds to execute each query on the db end. The network connection looked clear too, so I've no idea where the lag was. I'll mark this as accepted since it prompted me to the solution.

Comment: There are two ways that I know of to get around the issue.  One is to use a custom component as an "uploader" to place the files into your file system, instead. Another thing is a sort of external blob storage.  However, from your last comment (thanks for the points, by the way) you seem to say that what causes you to lose time is from your query processing a request where it has to filter out jpeg files?  So the real solution was optimizing your query?

Comment: Not quite. The issue was that, when opening more than one result set at the same time, the code just hung for a few seconds. This reasoning seems to hold, since the other areas in our codebase that lagged were doing the same thing, and areas that weren't doing that didn't lag. I've refactored them to now use JOINs, or hold the results in a temporary list before doing the subsequent queries. Much faster now :)

Comment: Absolutely clueless as to *why* that's causing a problem though. My colleague noticed the same issue a while back and just avoided using multiple result set handles at once. It's probably not worth the time to go dig into the code to work it out.

Comment: In your db, is your data sufficiently granualized?  I mean, when you query the fields, do you have to do a complicated text comparison, with say, regex?  That can slow things down too.  For example, if you query persons' names, if you make first names to be one field and last names to be one field instead of putting them together in the same field -- it is much faster to query the names rather than using text-comparisons to get at them if they were stuck together.

Comment: Nope, the query is on a single index. As I mentioned before, it's super fast on the database end, but super slow in the app. I'm guessing our data adapter component is broken in some way, but it's too much effort to dig through and figure out why.

Comment: Okay.  God bless!

Answer (score 0):

Joins can press the envelope on tempdb performance.  Generally speaking, tempdb should be the fastest and most optimized database on the server.  The reality is often quite different.

Tempdb should be on an ssd, and it should not be configured to auto-grow.  Auto-grow can be a huge performance killer.  On a production system, tempdb should have one partition/file per processor core.

Comment: This is just a lowly dev machine running on a laptop. Same goes for everyone else. Nobody else gets the problem.